# Using PHP to access a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to access a MySQL database using PHP.

Can someone please explain the basic steps involved in doing that?

Comment: Maybe you are also interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-a-database-from-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the `mysqli` extension as opposed to the old, insecure `mysql` extension.

First get familiar with database design, SQL and MySQL, then follow this [link](http://www.willfitch.com/mysqli-tutorial.html).

Still want an example? Here you go:

```
<?php
$host = 'YOUR HOSTNAME HERE';
$user = 'YOUR USERNAME HERE';
$pass = 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE';
$db_name = 'YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE';

$db = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $db_name );

if( $db->errno ) {
  // an error occurred.
  exit();
}
...
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM some_table;';    

$result_set = $db->query( $sql );

...fetch results...

while( $obj = $result_set->fetch_object() ) {
   $value = $obj->some_property;
   ...do something with $value...
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Nuff said.

Good luck!

Comment: lol theres a up arrow and a checkmark, you can click on both.

Comment: Be aware that you probably don't want anyone else see your database errors. `echo $db->error;` is only a good idea while you're debugging.